# Quicker way to break loop or increment counter?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, counter, break

Is there a quicker way to increment a counter or break from an outer loop?

```
while(myArrayList.get(i) > myNumber) {
    // some operations

    if(i + 1 < myArrayList.size())
        i++;
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: "Quicker" in what way?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Quicker => better, quicker is not always better. ;)

Comment: in cases no member of your ArrayList is bigger than **myNumber** the code causes OutOfBoundException finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to write your code is definitely there:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
    if (myArrayList.get(i) <= myNumber) break;
    //Some operations...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the size first to avoid running off the end of the list and getting an error.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) 
    if (myArrayList.get(i) <= myNumber)
        break;
```

With the Streams API you could do

```
int n = IntStream.range(0, myArrayList.size())
                 .filter(i -> myArrayList.get(i) <= myNumber)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(myArrayList.size()); // or -1
```

Answer (score 1):

A for-loop is more appropriate here:

```
int counter = 0

for(int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
    if(!(myArrayList.get(i) > myNumber)) {
        break;
    }

    counter++;
}
```

If the intention is count values that are greater than `myNumber`, then `break` will possibly exclude some values (unless you know that `myArrayList` is sorted), and the loop should rather be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
    if(myArrayList.get(i) > myNumber) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first case, you only need on counter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think so too, but it seems the goal is to count elements that meet the `!(myArrayList.get(i) > myNumber)` condition, in which case I suppose the count will be used outside the loop.

Comment: The question seems to be about how to break from a loop. If you count the those which pass a test, you would not use `break;`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Right. Breaking is exactly what the first snippet does. The second snippet is for the case of counting (although that is not in the question, I suspect it could be the goal as the scope of `i` is broader than the `while` loop)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to start counting from some index `i`,

```
int count=0;
    for( ;((i < myArrayList.size()-1) && (myArrayList.get(i) > myNumber));i++){
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: You most like want to check the size first.

Comment: I think there is one too many `)` and if you have `i` why do you need `j` as it should always be the same?

Comment: i thought he may want to start counting from so index `i` mid way